# Get 404 error when connecting to apollo graphQL server from browser

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I setup apollo graphql server in nodejs. Below is the source code. I can launch the server and it start listening on port 6000. But I got `This site can’t be reached` when I open the url (`http://localhost:6000/graphiql`) in browser. I wonder what wrong with my code.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const { graphqlExpress, graphiqlExpress } = require('apollo-server-express');
const { makeExecutableSchema } = require('graphql-tools');

// Some fake data
const books = [
  {
    title: "Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's stone",
    author: 'J.K. Rowling',
  },
  {
    title: 'Jurassic Park',
    author: 'Michael Crichton',
  },
];

// The GraphQL schema in string form
const typeDefs = `
  type Query { books: [Book] }
  type Book { title: String, author: String }
`;

// The resolvers
const resolvers = {
  Query: { books: () => books },
};

// Put together a schema
const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
});

// Initialize the app
const app = express();

// The GraphQL endpoint
app.use('/graphql', bodyParser.json(), graphqlExpress({ schema }));

// GraphiQL, a visual editor for queries
app.use('/graphiql', graphiqlExpress({ endpointURL: '/graphql' }));

// Start the server
app.listen(6000, () => {
  console.log('Go to http://localhost:6000/graphiql to run queries!');
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a port issue, port `6000` is one of the ports not consider safe for most browsers, even though you can curl it on the terminal. For example this should work:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:6000/graphql \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"query": "{ books { title } }"}'
```

But running it on the browser should not, as the port is restricted.
You can see the list of restricted ports on [Chrome](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/refs/heads/master/net/base/port_util.cc) and [Firefox](https://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/netlib/PortBanning.html#portlist), other browser should also follow this rules.

If you change your port to 4000 (for example, or any other unrestricted port) everything should work fine.